# Angular2: Autofocus does not work on view 'refresh' (angular)

Tags: angular

I'm building a QuizTool/LMS similar in nature to Duolingo (SPA-ish).

**tldr:** Hit the plnkr, 'Check Answers', 'Do Another', and notice the first input element no longer has the input focus -- even tho the 'autofocus' property seems to be set correctly. Can I fix this?

https://embed.plnkr.co/DU8opUuquP5MXlcfdHIe/

**long version:** When I first render a quiz, I am able to set the input focus (using a bound `autofocus` property) into the first input area on the screen (a TEXTAREA where the user will answer the first question) -- so the user can just start typing away. Excellent.

However, once the user has submitted that first set of questions (the first quiz), the user can choose to 'Do Another' quiz -- I/Angular am able to redraw a new quiz/UI (with, for now, what happen to be the same exact questions), only the 'autofocus' attribute does not seem to work -- i.e. the first input/textarea does not get the focus.

It does appear that the bound `autofocus` attribute is set, however.

Which means either:
1) i'm reading the attribute incorrectly somehow
2) it's a bug in Chrome (Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) on Mac OSX)
3) something is getting/stealing the focus after this field's autofocus is correctly set
4) etc.

I've set up 'firstQuestion' and 'lastQuestion' local vars in the `ngFor` loop to help prove that the autofocus property is being set deterministically (just change the `[autofocus]="firstQuestion"` to `[autofocus]="lastQuestion"`).

I'm open to fixing this however I need to. The whole 'no controller' thing is pretty new to me, so it's very possible I'm doing something stupid with this entire setup.

I have tried using Angular forms/ngForm but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

I'd also be curious to know where I could find a basic tutorial on Angular2 transitions/'controller' stuff -- i.e. how do I redraw a screen, or switch to a new view, etc. -- without what might be considered a 'traditional' controller. I think with VB you said something like:

`oldForm.hide();
newForm.show();`

If none of this works, I want to set the focus manually/jqLite/pre-HTML5/whatever -- haven't had much success there yet either -- thus this question.

Thank you.

---

Not sure how useful this is, but it seems my app -- which was set up with the ng cli tool -- is different significantly than what plunkr is producing.

i was able to discover that:

1. even if the 'document.activeElement' was set to the correct textarea (according to querying the DOM), it might still not be activate for the user to start inputting text (I set a red bg to make it very visual), and
2. the outer/hosting index.html page, shown below, was getting the focus after my component finished loading. i added a hack javascript function to manually push the focus back to my desired element, but it was really just for testing.

   ```
   <script>
        setInterval(function(){ 
           if(document.activeElement!=null){
               if(document.activeElement.id!='textarea-0'){ // find first input element on the page
                   document.getElementById('textarea-0').focus(); // set the focus
               }
           } 
       },
       5000);                
   </script>
   ```

---

**Update:**

Fixed. Thanks again to @mickdev.

This is a small twist on the first solution. I'd describe it as "using a template reference variable with the ngAfterViewChecked() lifecycle method on the component you are rendering".

---

Add this stuff to the component you are rendering:

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('focusThis') focusThis;

// to keep track of which element in our loop we are in
id:number=0 

//wait for viewchild to update then focus
ngAfterViewChecked(){
    // only focus the 0th (i.e. first) element of our loop
    if(this.id == 0){
        this.focusThis.nativeElement.focus();
        this.id++
    }
}
```

Then add the template reference variable, '#focusThis':

```
<textarea   #focusThis
            [(ngModel)]="question.useranswer" 
            [disabled]="quiz.wasEvaluated"...
```

Comment: autofocus property has firstQuestion and firstQuestion has value of first. but i didn't find value of first.

Comment: 'first' is automatically created by [angular's `*ngFor` directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html). i gave it another name, `firstQuestion`, to try to be even more explicit about what i was using it for. if it is the first element of the `ngFor` directive, then 'first' will be a boolean `true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a (ugly) workaround but it works :)
First, import ViewChild

```
import {Component, NgModule, ViewChild} from '@angular/core'

@ViewChild('test') test;

doAnother() {
    this.quiz = new Quiz();

    this.test.nativeElement.focus(); 
}
```

Then update the view :

```
<div><textarea [autofocus]="firstQuestion" #test></textarea></div>
```

Here is a working plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/S6wRn3tUTxZcOQdojzr6?p=preview

**Update**: here is a more elegant way to achieve this `ElementRef`

```
//component
import {Component, NgModule, ElementRef} from '@angular/core'

this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('#textarea-1').focus()

//template
<div><textarea id="textarea-{{ question.id }}" [autofocus]="firstQuestion"></textarea></div>
```

Now, you can target any textarea in your DOM. Here is a working plunker : 
https://plnkr.co/edit/izH61uVHBreEwdVQNoSf?p=preview

Comment: wow, definitely seems to work. but how? i see the [template reference variable docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars), but...won't every question/textarea in my question-list declare and bind that value? i.e. does that template reference variable, referred to by `this.test.nativeElement`, only get bound once, the very first time through the `*ngFor`?

Comment: The Dom can focus only one element at the time. So it will focus the first one. You can also target the first `<textarea>`if you want.

Comment: see my updated answer for a more elegant way to achieve what you want :)

Comment: thank you, that looks cool too. i will generally always want the very first input field that the user can actually type into -- so, non-disabled, non-hidden, etc. and i will know those things as i lay out the questions in the `ngFor` loop, so i should just be able to use a loop counter in place of the `{{question.id}}` in your second solution. i think i have all that right. thanks again, great stuff.

Comment: i'm actually looking at this again. tho the plunkers all work, and the plunker is almost identical to my setup, it must not be, because none of the solutions work in my actual code on my laptop. i tried disabling all chrome extensions to no avail. if i eventually find out what's going on, i'll post back. i've been trying the various lifecycle methods, but something weird happening there too. it's almost like there's some monitor process constantly making tweaks to the UI, even without any user input.

Comment: this is weird indeed. If you want me to look at it let me know

Comment: would love any further input. we're trying to do this open source, so it's all available online. Demo: http://wh-dev01.fourmajor.com:4200/ and source: https://github.com/fourmajor/quiztool This version is basically before I tried all your fixes, so it is still 'properly broken'. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137771/discussion-between-mickdev-and-peter-smith).

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" #myInput />
{{ myInput.focus() }}
```

Just add {{ myInput.focus() }} right after input inside template

Comment: This kind of works but it sticks the focus to that input forever. If you click in some other input, the focus doesn't shift to the new input, at least not for me.

Comment: that's correct. this method is useful for form with one input only.