# Angular 5 Autofocus

Tags: angular, angular5

I have an `Angular 5` project and I want to set an autofocus to any item on the page when it loads.

Closest I have got is in the following plunka

https://plnkr.co/edit/OfdnZzGx0KgbCMh3IlE4?p=preview

The only issue is that I'm not using `Directives` I'm using `Components`, `Models` and 'Services'

I want to try and stay away from `Directives` if possible but I cant get my pluka to work using these.

Any suggestions

Comment: I tried the solution posted by Sergey Gurin in here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50387778/5354296 <input type="text" #myInput /> {{ myInput.focus() }} Just add {{ myInput.focus() }} right after input inside template.
Tested in Angular2 successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not to simply use `autofocus` attribute on input filed like this -

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" autofocus>
```

## [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ung6ft?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanks don't why i didn't use this :-). Only issue i have is when on a page with tabs, if i click another tab it doesn't `autofocus` to the first field on that tab. Any suggestions for this

Comment: you can manually/forcefully set autofocus to specific input conditionally

Comment: That stackblitz is working for me in Chrome but not in Firefox. Seems to be due to the way firefox handles forms that are created via javascript. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955398/autofocus-attribute-of-html5-does-not-work-only-in-firefox-when-forminput-ar

Comment: I don't think so there is any relation with routerModule, though I am not fully sure.

Comment: @PardeepJain This is by far the simplest way. Just tried it, didn't see first name is focused. Is it me?

Comment: @Jeb50 yes this is the default HTML attribute for input element, to make it more prominent you have to add forcefully event on input using javascript's `focus` event.

Comment: arofocus only work in SPA if the element is loaded just after first page load/ reload. If you then use routing to navigate to different page, it does not work there.